# Debug Error in Orchard Project cannot be made app relative: Too many '..'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

Orchard.FileSystems.VirtualPath.DefaultVirtualPathProvider - (null) - INFO Path '~/Modules/Markdown/../../../packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3/lib/net45/System.Web.Helpers.dll' cannot be made app relative: Too many '..'

I am finding this error at debug time in all the orchard modules.
Project is not start successfully. 
Same error of different dll is coming in my log.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the [Orchard source](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard/FileSystems/VirtualPath/DefaultVirtualPathProvider.cs#L74), where this log has been generated. Your packages folder is outside of the application root.